# JOIN 2 tables based on StartDate and EndDate column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have 2 tables as described in the SQL below:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(   
    [ForeignKeyID] INT
    ,[Name] CHAR
    ,[StartDate] DATE
    ,[FinishDate] DATE
);

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(   
    [ForeignKeyID] INT
    ,[StartDate] DATE
    ,[EndDate] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @Table1 ([ForeignKeyID], [Name], [StartDate], [FinishDate])
VALUES (1, 'A', '20210101', '20210103')
      ,(1, 'B', '20210103', NULL);

INSERT INTO @Table2 ([ForeignKeyID], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES (1, '20210101', '20210102')
      ,(1, '20210102', '20210103')
      ,(1, '20210103', '20210104')
      ,(1, '20210104', '20210105')
      ,(1, '20210105', '20210106');

SELECT
    t2.ForeignKeyID, t2.StartDate, t2.EndDate, t1.Name AS OnDuty
FROM 
    @Table2 t2
    INNER JOIN @Table1 t1 ON t2.ForeignKeyID = t1.ForeignKeyID
-- WHERE ??? 
ORDER BY t2.StartDate;
```

I want to get a result table as shown below. I have tried, but the issue is with the NULL values in the FinishDate column in Table1.

| ForeignKeyID | StartDate | EndDate | OnDuty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-Jan-21 | 2-Jan-21 | A |
| 1 | 2-Jan-21 | 3-Jan-21 | A |
| 1 | 3-Jan-21 | 4-Jan-21 | B |
| 1 | 4-Jan-21 | 5-Jan-21 | B |
| 1 | 5-Jan-21 | 6-Jan-21 | B |

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, I will try to edit. The LEFT JOIN doesn't give a result as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing at your logic here (be best if you could add the logic to your question), but a combination or `and` / `or` logic to compare the dates depending on whether `FinishDate` is null or not should do the trick.

```
SELECT t2.ForeignKeyID, t2.StartDate, t2.EndDate, t1.[Name] AS OnDuty
FROM @Table2 t2
INNER JOIN @Table1 t1 ON t2.ForeignKeyID = t1.ForeignKeyID
WHERE t2.StartDate >= t1.StartDate
AND (t2.StartDate < t1.FinishDate OR t1.FinishDate IS NULL)
ORDER BY t2.StartDate;
```